# IBM Server configuration

Tags: apache, ssh

i have an ibm server, a tp-link router with an static ip and DHCP activated, i want to configure one of the net boards in the ibm server.

I installed Ububntu server and access to the net board configuration using this command:

vi /etc/network/interfaces

I configure the server with this

address -> i put an ip that i resrve in the router

netmask

network

broadcast

gateway

I have a subdomain from no ip i have entered in the server so i can do remote connection to the server throw this subdomain and ssh. I have put the subdomain in /etc/host.conf

The thing is i have access to the subdomain in the web and out of the LAN net. But when i try to connect to the server throw ssh it's gave me connection refused.

EDIT:
Using the command arp-scan -I eth0 -l i found that the IP of the server is asigned two times it's look like it's the same ethernet board with two MAC address thar are the same except the las number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, what's work for me was to reinstall openssh on the server and in my computer. After that I have access throw ssh.